# How do I keep track of the time the CPU is used vs the GPUs for deep learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I'm interested in knowing how much time of my script runtime is spent on the CPU vs the GPU - is there a way to track this?

Looking for a generic answer, but if that's too abstract one for this toy solution (from keras's `multi_gpu_model` examples) would be great.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.applications import Xception
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
import numpy as np
num_samples = 1000
height = 224
width = 224
num_classes = 1000
# Instantiate the base model (or "template" model).
# We recommend doing this with under a CPU device scope,
# so that the model's weights are hosted on CPU memory.
# Otherwise they may end up hosted on a GPU, which would
# complicate weight sharing.
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    model = Xception(weights=None,
                     input_shape=(height, width, 3),
                     classes=num_classes)
# Replicates the model on 8 GPUs.
# This assumes that your machine has 8 available GPUs.
parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=8)
parallel_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                       optimizer='rmsprop')
# Generate dummy data.
x = np.random.random((num_samples, height, width, 3))
y = np.random.random((num_samples, num_classes))
# This `fit` call will be distributed on 8 GPUs.
# Since the batch size is 256, each GPU will process 32 samples.
parallel_model.fit(x, y, epochs=20, batch_size=256)
# Save model via the template model (which shares the same weights):
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to add is the Chrome-based `timeline` profiling for both CPU/GPU from Tensorflow API to your Keras model!

Here is example provided in Tensorflow issue tracker:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9868#issuecomment-306188267

This is a more complicated example in Keras issue tracker:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6606#issuecomment-380196635

Finally this is how the output of this profiling looks like:

https://towardsdatascience.com/howto-profile-tensorflow-1a49fb18073d

[image]